# Using GROUP BY and ORDER BY Together to retrive the latest messages

Tags: mysql

I' am making a messaging system, I need to Group the messages by the Sender and Order by Descending order so that the latest message will always be on top.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    messages.message_id, 
    messages.message_from, 
    messages.message_to, 
    messages.message_content, 
    messages.message_seen, 
    messages.message_datetime, 
    messages.message_status, 
    profiles.profile_id, 
    profiles.profile_photo, 
    profiles.profile_username, 
    profiles.profile_name 
FROM 
    messages 
INNER JOIN 
    PROFILES 
WHERE 
    profiles.profile_id = messages.message_from
GROUP BY 
    messages.message_from
ORDER BY 
    messages.message_id DESC
```

**This is what the above Query Shows.**

[image]

**This is how the database structure looks like**
[image]

As you can see, the **message_id** is in descending order but its not the latest id.

**Question:**

How can I use Group By and Order By together to show the latest messages from the database from the Database Query above, What am I missing?

Comment: What is the latest message_id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do it as below, I have not selected all the fields you can add the fields that is needed in the selection list

```
select 
m.message_id,
m.message_from,
m.message_to,
p.profile_name
from messages m
join profiles p on p.profile_id = m.message_from
left join messages m1 
on m1.message_from = m.message_from
and m.message_id < m1.message_id
where 
m1.message_id is null
order by m.message_id desc
```

Another way of doing the same is as

```
select 
m.message_id,
m.message_from,
m.message_to,
p.profile_name
from messages m
join profiles p on p.profile_id = m.message_from
where not exists
(
  select 1 from messages m1
  where 
  m1.message_from = m.message_from
  and m.message_id < m1.message_id
)
order by m.message_id desc
```

**[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/378a9/2)**

Comment: This is a good idea. I would like to suggest to @RedVirus though, that you should filter for the latest date and not necessarily the latest id if you're trying to get the most *recent* message, but only do that if it actually makes sense in your context.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you really want to do here is get the first item from a group. This is a common question that is always disguised in different ways, see this [article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) for more info.

So, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT
   m.message_id,
   m.message_from,
   m.message_to,
   m.message_content
   m.message_seen
   m.message_datetime,
   m.message_status,
   p.profile_id,
   p.profile_photo,
   p.profile_username,
   p.profile_name
FROM message m
JOIN profiles p ON p.profile_id = m.message_from
WHERE(
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM message msg
   WHERE msg.message_from = m.message_from AND msg.message_datetime <= m.message_datetime
   ) <= 1
ORDER BY m.message_id DESC;
```

So what the subquery in the where clause will do is pull the latest message for each message_from id. I made a slight change here to pull the latest date, and not just the latest message_id value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    t2.maxID, 
    messages.message_from, 
    messages.message_to, 
    messages.message_content, 
    messages.message_seen, 
    messages.message_datetime, 
    messages.message_status, 
    profiles.profile_id, 
    profiles.profile_photo, 
    profiles.profile_username, 
    profiles.profile_name 
FROM 
    messages LEFT JOIN PROFILES 
    ON profiles.profile_id = messages.message_from
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(message_id) AS maxID,message_from FROM messages GROUP BY message_from) t2
    ON messages.message_from = t2.message_from
GROUP BY 
    messages.message_from
ORDER BY 
    t2.maxID DESC
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I believe your answer is same as my question. It's also giving me same results.

Comment: @RedVirus Please see update on my answer. Just hit like if this work.

Comment: It's a lot better when you can at least give some explanation for the changes you are making rather than dropping a block of code like this. Even if it did solve their problem, it doesn't help them moving forward or aid new users who stumble upon this question.